# Why Centos 8 iso images doesn't boot as a CD in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, centos-8

I'm trying to install Centos 8 on Virtualbox in Windows.

When loaded in the virtual CD drive, the official .iso doesn't boot.

I got the message :
"FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted."

I tried the 3 iso (boot, minimal and DVD1), checksums are good, boot order too, any other bootable iso I try the same way works fine.

Are the official iso broken ?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that I downloaded the ARM64 version thinking it was AMD64.

Hope it will help someone not loosing time on this... ;-(